# jar not working on linux : ClassCastException / javax / cannot be cast to

Tags: java, executable-jar

I'm trying to run a .jar on a 64bits fedora, which runs perfectly on windows.

At first I try :

```
java -version  
java version "1.6.0_17"  
java -jar myprog_TABS_Dec30.jar
```

And I got :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode cannot be cast to myprog.view.tree.DataObject_Node
```

Then I checked :

```
file Analyseries2011_TABS.class
Analyseries2011_TABS.class: compiled Java class data, version 49.0 (Java 1.5)
```

So I installed : jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-amd64-rpm.bin :

```
/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_22/bin/java -jar myprog_TABS_Dec30.jar
```

Result :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter
```

Finally I looked after MANIFEST.MF inside the META-INF directory :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.7.0_01-b08 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: 
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: myprog.core.main.myprog_TABS
```

Ok let's try :

```
/usr/java/jre1.7.0_01/bin/java -jar myprog_TABS_Dec30.jar
```

Guess what...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode cannot be cast to myprog.view.tree.DataObject_Node
```

I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Do you actually have such a cast?

Comment: Could you post some code? At least your DataObject_Node class and the place you cast it to a DefaultMutableTreeNode?

Comment: I don't have the source, I'm just trying to make it run actually... I'll try to open this class and get back to you if I manage to read it.

Comment: It will not be easy to understand what's happening without the source...

Answer (score 1):

javax.swing.filechooser.[FileNameExtensionFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html) was introduced in Java 6, so it's no wonder you are not able to compile your code with Java 5.0.

As you don't have access to the source code, we will have to guess what's happening. A ClassCastException means the code does something like:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode object1 = doSomething();
DataObject_Node object2 = (DataObject_Node)object1;
```

But DataObject_Node is not a subclass of DefaultMutableTreeNode, so you get a ClassCastException because you can't do that. So, to me, it looks like a bug in the code.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know, but now I'm still wondering why it's not compiling with Java 6 and 7.

Comment: As everyone's saying if it can't be solved without the source I guess I'll have to close my question. I didn't think of that because this .jar works on windows, so I was looking more into an environment issue.

Comment: I can't understand how it could work on Windows. Are you sure both jars are the same?

Comment: You make me doubt :), but I just checked and it's running.

Answer (score 1):

***One possible (far fetched) cause:***

If it runs on one OS and not another, one has to remember, that java (still?) uses native code for zipping/unzipping as jars are in the zip format. Nowadays (java 7) java.util.zip can handle encodings, but who knows.

Maybe you used a package or class name, in another encoding. Look with 7zip in the jar. Or come to think of it, with a `$` in the name.

Comment: I have looked into the .jar with the "archive manager" not 7zip, and I have some "$" in the filenames of some classes... is it what you are talking about ? And I'm pretty sure that the software has been built on windows.

Comment: No, but '$' are used by the compiler to make file names for the inner classes and such. As I saw the underscore in the names, I wondered whether some names had special characters - like `public class DataNode_Object extends MyFaçade` - 'ç'. Or a package (folder) name.

Comment: I checked the names and got nothing special only letters upper and lower numbers and $.

Comment: Another tip, try installing OpenJDK on Windows and try it out with that version. Maybe it was Oracle JDK/Open JDK (but why there).